# Operation over iterators in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have some problem in translating some rows of code from ANSI C and arrays, to C++ with vectors.

To operate iteratively along the element of the array, in ANSI C, I wrote:

```
int i;
struct Sys{
   double *v;
};
Sys sys; sys.v = malloc(10*sizeof(double));
//initialize the array with some values...
{...}
for (i = 5; i < 10; i++){ //overwrite the cumulative sum starting from position 4
   sys.v[i] =  sys.v[i] + function_that_return_a_double(i);
}
```

Now, I wont to translate in C++ with vectors. Here is my trial.

```
Sys {
    vector<double> v;
};
Sys sys;
sys.v.resize(10);
// initialize the vector with some values...
{...}
for (vector<double>::iterator it = sys.v.begin() + 5; it != sys.v.end(); ++it){ //yyy
   k = k+1;
   tmp = function_that_return_a_double(k);
   *it = *it + tmp; //xxx
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
code.cpp:xxx: error: name lookup of ‘it’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
code.cpp:xxx: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

If i complile with -fpermissive, I get:

```
code.cpp:xxx: warning: name lookup of ‘it’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
code.cpp:yyy: warning:   using obsolete binding at ‘it’
```

I don't undenstand if this is the right way to use the iterators and STD:vector

I hope you can solve my doubts,

Cheers,

Al.

PS: I corrected the declaration of v in the c++ case. v is not a pointer!
PPS: The code snippet is fine!! see below.

Comment: How does `sys.v.begin()` compile when `v` is a pointer?

Comment: Also, what's `Sys {
    vector<double> *v;
};`?

Comment: You actually start at position 6 there.

Comment: Should it be sys->v.begin()?

Comment: Sorry, in fact v is not a pointer in the orginal code. I correct the mistake up on the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `Sys` as a struct or a class:

```
struct Sys {
    vector<double> *v;
};
```

You are attempting to access `v` as though it is vector. Use `->` because it is a *pointer to a vector*.

```
Sys sys;
sys.v->resize(10);

for (vector<double>::iterator it = sys.v->begin(); it != sys.v->end(); ++it) {
    *it += function_that_returns_a_double(k); // Define k somewhere.
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for this. In truth v is not a pointer. I corrected the question. k is the variable that grows each iteration.

Comment: @altroware The error message you are encountering commonly occurs when you access `it` outside of the for-loop scope. Your code snippet is fine, are you using it anywhere else?

Comment: Nice to know that the code snippet is fine. Actually there where a missing curly bracket in the original code. I learnt the lesson, thank you very much.